# Is there an easy way to generate an Ant build script from a Maven POM?

Tags: java, maven-2, ant, build, pom.xml

We have a project that uses Maven as its build/dependency management tool. But our code needs to be compiled at our client's site and our client demands that we deliver build scripts written for Ant.

So, we would like to keep working with Maven and automatically generate the Ant scripts when we need to deliver the code to the client.

Can we do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [Maven Ant Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ant-plugin/).

Comment: Thanks! That's what I needed. I had googled for it and found only the other plugin that can run Ant tasks within Maven builds.

Comment: but that plugin is used in maven builds.I need to work in ant build env.
hence need to do some editing in build.xml of ant tool.